# Trying to Transform this Trigger to HelperClass

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I wrote the trigger and it works great but now I need to transform it into a helperclass so I can reference it on our master trigger for the Case object! This is my first trigger to ever write and I just finished my second trigger on a custom object that references a helperclass I created. I am trying to copy what I did on that helperclass but am getting stuck on (a) how to define "case" fields at the beginning in a class (b) so I can reference these case field to say don't fire unless these field criteria are true.

---

```
trigger CaseMineSite on Case (after insert, after update){

  List<ID> AccountIds = New List<ID>();

   for(Case c : Trigger.new){

    if(c.Reason == 'Image Acquisition' && c.Triage_Queue_Routing__c == 'Mine Site Queue'){

      AccountIds.add(c.Accountid);
    }
  }

  List<Account> AccountList = [SELECT id, Image_Case_Type__c FROM Account WHERE id in :AccountIds];

  for(integer i = 0 ; i < AccountList.size(); i++){

    AccountList[i].Image_Case_Type__c = 'Mine Site Queue';
  }

  update AccountList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your trigger runs in a static context, you are able to reference the variables from the trigger in other static methods. For an example if we were to move the logic out of the trigger into a helper class, your code will look something like the following:

**Trigger**

```
trigger CaseMineSite on Case (after insert, after update)
{
    if (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        CaseTriggerHandler.afterInsertUpdate();
    }
}
```

**Class**

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler
{
    public static void afterInsertUpdate()
    {
        List<ID> AccountIds = New List<ID>();

        // Generic SObject
        for (sObject caseRecord : Trigger.new)
        {
            // Cast to a concrete SObject, or use (DataType)caseRecord.get('fieldName')
            Case c = (Case)caseRecord;

            if (c.Reason == 'Image Acquisition' && c.Triage_Queue_Routing__c == 'Mine Site Queue')
            {
                AccountIds.add(c.Accountid);
            }
        }

        List<Account> AccountList = [SELECT id, Image_Case_Type__c FROM Account WHERE id in :AccountIds];

        for(integer i = 0 ; i < AccountList.size(); i++)
        {
            AccountList[i].Image_Case_Type__c = 'Mine Site Queue';
        }

        update AccountList;
    }
}
```

*I haven't tested this, it might need some tweaking around, generally this is the idea in a nutshell*

Comment: hi, is it going to work or we should accept trigger.new as input parameter? Something like this - CaseTriggerHandler.afterInsertUpdate(trigger.new) and in the method - public static void afterInsertUpdate(list<case> cases)

Comment: You don't need to pass `trigger.new` as a parameter, it's accessible in your static method by default when you call the method from the trigger. It's a static variable

Comment: I really dislike using static trigger references outside of the trigger body fwiw.

Comment: You can pass them as parameters to your static methods